# Sequelize - Build dynamic where clause with 'Op.or'

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I had this code block working with Sequelize v5.  But since switching to v6, it seems to be erroring out.  I am getting the error: `Error: Invalid value { customer_id: 'dg5j5435r4gfd' }`.

And here is the code that creates the where condition block:

```js
    let whereBlock = {
        deleted_at: null,
    };

    if (args.includeCore) {
        if (customerID !== 'all') {
            // whereBlock[Op.or] = [
            //  { customer_id: customerID },
            //  { customer_id: coreCustomerID },
            // ];
            whereBlock[Op.or] = [];
            whereBlock[Op.or].push({
                customer_id: customerID,
            });
            whereBlock[Op.or].push({ customer_id: coreCustomerID });
        }
    } else {
        whereBlock.customer_id = customerID;
    }
```

I was using the commented code.  And then I tried the code below that.  Both are producing the same error.  But when I remove all that code from the if block and just put in `whereBlock.customer_id = customerID;`, then it works fine.  So I know the issue is how I am constructing the where condition.

**Update:** As requested, here is my `Sheets` model where the where clause is being run on.

```js
'use strict';

export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define(
        'Sheet',
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
                primaryKey: true,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            },
            sheet_name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                isAlphaNumeric: true,
                required: true,
                allowNull: true,
                len: [3, 80],
            },
            sheet_file_name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                unique: true,
                isAlphaNumeric: true,
                required: false,
                allowNull: true,
            },
            brand_name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                unique: false,
                isAlphaNumeric: true,
                required: false,
                allowNull: true,
            },
            customer_id: {
                // fk in customers table
                type: DataTypes.TINYINT(2).UNSIGNED,
                required: true,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            chemical_id: {
                // fk in loads table
                type: DataTypes.SMALLINT.UNSIGNED,
                required: true,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            load_id: {
                // fk in loads table
                type: DataTypes.SMALLINT.UNSIGNED,
                required: true,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            active: {
                type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
                required: true,
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: true,
            },
            created_at: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
            },
            updated_at: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
            },
            deleted_at: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
            },
        },
        {
            underscored: true,
            paranoid: false,
        }
    );
};
```

And in my index I have this to associate sheets with customers: `db.Sheet.belongsTo(db.Customer);`

Also here is the full code where the `whereBlock` is used, if that helps:

```js
const files = await db.Sheet.findAll({
                raw: true,
                attributes: [
                    'sheet_name',
                    'sheet_file_name',
                    ['brand_name', 'brand'],
                    'updated_at',
                    'active',
                    [Sequelize.col('Chemical.name'), 'chemical'],
                    [Sequelize.col('Load.value'), 'load'],
                ],
                include: [
                    {
                        model: db.Load.scope(null),
                        required: true,
                        as: 'Load',
                        attributes: ['value'],
                    },
                    {
                        model: db.Chemical.scope(null),
                        required: true,
                        as: 'Chemical',
                        attributes: ['name'],
                    },
                ],
                // model: model,
                where: whereBlock,
                order: [['active', 'DESC']],
            });
```

**TLDR:** So here is what it comes down to:

```js
whereBlock = {
    deleted_at: null,
    customer_id: customerID,
    // [Op.or]: [
    //  { customer_id: customerID },
    //  { customer_id: coreCustomerID },
    // ],
};
```

That code above works, but the commented code errors out with: `Error: Invalid value { customer_id: '123456' }`

Comment: Could you post your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is very weird.  But I finally figured out the issue!!  Was not something I would have thought of, just found it by chance.  It was the way I was importing `Op` from `sequelize`.

`import Op from 'sequelize';`

So apparently, that `Op` object has another object inside it called `Op`.  So when I call my `[Op.or]`, I instead need to do this: `[Op.Op.or]`.

I did try switching my import to `import Op.Op from 'sequelize';` and that caused errors.  Anyone know how I can properly import the inner object?

### Update

OK, so apparently in my other DB files, I was doing the import differently.

```js
export default (db) => {
    const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;
```

That method works to pull in the correct `Op` object.  So there you go.  Hopefully this nightmare issue helps someone else in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure why I couldn't have gotten a nice clean error in my console along the lines of `"or" command not recgonized on line xxx`